# Authorise more than one Facebook app at a time

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth, facebook-oauth

I work for an organisation that is partnering with another group. Each of us will have a body of users logged into Facebook. What we want to do is to make it possible for a user who is signed in under my group's app id to see all his/her friends some of whom will also be logged in under that id, some of whom will be logged in under the partner org's app id.

The idea we had in mind was that it might be possible to grant permissions on auth to both app ids in one go. Is that possible? If not, does anyone have any idea how we could share this kind of presence data without also sharing all other user details?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible, though I don't see why you can't just use the same App to have multiple pieces of functionality

Comment: It's not multiple pieces of functionality in one app. It is two different apps owned by two different companies that need to pool some of their data. Here is a scenario:

Two users -- User A, User B
Two companies: Company A, Company B

User A logs in through Company A's app
User B, a friend of User A logs in through Company B's app

All we want is that when each company's app shows the user which of his/her friends are viewing an event (we already can share these), User A and User B can see each other.

I'm sorry if this seems a bit vague. I can't talk about the details for commercial reasons.

Comment: Well pooling the data like that is explicitly against policy as far as I know (have your legal people check section 2 of https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ ) ; you should be able to find a way to use the same app to perform both functions, or to link the apps in some way without relying on facebook data to do so